# Why is my Four O'Clock plant (Mirabilis jalapa) dying?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, fall-gardening

I live in Sydney. Its hardiness zone is 10b-11a (depending on the region). This autumn thus far has been warm and sunny with temperature range between 28C to 13C on average. Not too hot and not too cold. But my Four O'Clock, after flourishing in the hot summer, is now not flowering and its seed pods are yellowing. It is rather large in shape, if that helps.

All I know is that Four O Clocks 'die out' in the first frost, but we don't even have frost yet. And, as said, the weather these days has been rather warm. So what is going on exactly with the plant?

P.S. I have another large Four O'Clock in the front yard that is still flowering at parts. It acts as an annual, dying in late autumn and reemerging in late spring - Even though we live in a warm hardiness zone.

Thanks.

Comment: I live in zone 8 and nothing stops them here , except a freeze. They have become a weed . Even the deer leave them alone.

Comment: I've heard that they can be (or are) perennials in zones 8-10. Not sure why our ones, here in zone 10b, die out when the weather starts to cool. By cool I mean before even the first frost appears - and we barely have frosty mornings anyway. I'm wondering if there is way we can make them perennial? I envy those in cooler climates than ours, such as zone 8-9, that get to keep them thriving all winter. Lol.

Comment: To reiterate, they don't completely 'die out'. You would see others, since they're weedy and spreadable, emerging from ground in midwinter. But they don't grow much, and would would mature and flower by summer only, die off again in mid autumn, and repeat.